# Installation elasticsearch-head on Windows

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I installed `Elasticsearch` 5.6, and when I install a web front end `elasticsearch-head` by:

```
C:\elasticsearch\elasticsearch\bin>plugin -install mobz/elasticsearch-head
```

it return:

```
'plugin' n’est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes
```

Knowing that java is installed.

Some help please.
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Elastic's documentation for installing plugins](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/installation.html)

First off, the syntax you're using is for versions of Elastic prior to 5.x, so the command you're using here won't work.

[Documentation for the plugin you're trying to install](https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head) explicitly states that installation as a plugin for ElasticSearch is no longer supported 5.x and beyond.

> for Elasticsearch 5.x: site plugins are not supported. Run as a standalone server

You will want to run it using the plugin's built-in server if you plan to use 5.x. Plugin documentation [here](https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head#running-with-built-in-server).

Answer (score 0):

Try with following command,
elasticsearch-plugin -install mobz/elasticsearch-head